# Start learning Rails 3.2 or Rails 4.0 as a beginner? Improvements vs. resources/community?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I want to start learning Rails right now, what would make the most sense for a complete beginner? While Rails 4.0 is obviously newer and has many improvements there seem to be more resources/tutorials/established web apps that were made with 3.2. Do the advantages of 4.0 outweigh the lack of resources for 3.2? Also, will existing websites that use 3.2 update to 4.0? Thanks!

Comment: `the lack of resources for 3.2`? Not sure about that...

Comment: Rails 3 is meant to be replaced by Rails 4. If you start learning Rails 3, you will probably end up learning Rails 4 in the near future.  I think you can start directly with Rails 4

Comment: Also, if you are a total total beginner, I would recommend learning some ruby first. Books "Programming Ruby 1.9" and "Eloquent Ruby", in that order, should give you a nice push in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest going for Rails 4.0. Rails 4.0 is the latest **stable** release and the differences between Rails 3.2 and Rails 4.0 isn't that large.

I recommend the following resources to begin with:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org
- http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4

These are good starting points. The guides are great for small, informative and beginner friendly examples. The book is a great overall introduction to Rails and it has just been updated for Rails 4 (from 3.2).

Ryan Bates (founder of RailsCasts) briefly covers what's new in Rails 4. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4?view=asciicast.

Another great resource is http://objectsonrails.com, but I wouldn't start out with that one.

Comment: Also, the [Hartl Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) has both 3.2 and 4.0 versions.